# Buchstabieren = to spell?

Tags: idiom, dialect, yiddish

In another question Carsten mentioned that *buchstabieren* has a somewhat narrower meaning than to spell. I wonder if people would care to elaborate on this? Also, does German have the Yiddish variant *auslegen* for "to spell"? (also used as a noun as in "was is der rightig Ausleg?")

Comment: I think *buchstabieren* is **only** used for telling how to write/spell a word

Answer (score 2):

The verb *auslegen* has several meanings, the ones I can immediately think of being variations of "to display" and "to arrange". The literal translation is "to lay out". In my own experience, *auslegen* is not a term contemporarily used in Germany for spelling, but it could be in widespread use in the technical language(s) relevant to printing.

Off the top of my head, the verb *zu buchstabieren* translates to "to spell out, letter by letter". Even the colloquial uses are just about the same as in English; *Muß ich dir's buchstabieren?* is "Do I have to spell it out for you?". A conceivable alternative meaning of *buchstabieren* is to match the phonetics to a sequence of letters.

I don't know if the etymology of *Buchstabe*/"bookstaff" is a settled question; but one theory points to old Germanic roots, Buch/book referring to a rune stave, often carved into beech (Buche) wood. I.e., Buchstabe may have originally meant something like "a runestave made from beech". Be that as it may, the modern-day words retain the letter-by-letter quality.

Answer (score 2):

### auslegen / die Auslegung

Both these German terms are used for the process of text interpretation. This is not used for spelling, or conceiving single word meanings but rather for a more logical analysis of a written text as a whole (e.g. a law, the Bible, a contract).

Interestingly the English *"to spell"* origins from a no longer used German verb [*spellen*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS33818) used in the meaning of *to split something apart*.